# Append value in mysql column

Tags: mysql, csv

| name | id |
| --- | --- |
| Meete | 1,2 |
| Reza | 2,4 |
| dexer | Null |

I want to add 3,4 in id column , but number should not get repeat and keep previous values as it is

Output

| name | id |
| --- | --- |
| Meete | 1,2,3,4 |
| Reza | 2,3,4 |
| dexer | 3,4 |

Comment: You have already asked this question. It was closed - partially because of the absence of both details and your own attempts. Either add them or it will be closed too shortly.

Comment: @Akina either you answer the question or don't look at it

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Just don't store CSV values in a relational database! This basically defeats the purpose of a relational database. It is unsafe, unreliable, and highly inefficient.

What you ask for may look like a simple question to you, but is tedious to achieve: this typically requires splittig the string into rows, working something out, then rejoining into strings. That's a clear indication that your design is not adapted.

Each value in the CSV list should be stored on a separate row, like so:

```
name        id
--------------
Meete       1
Meete       1
Reza        2
Reza        4
```

With a primary key on `(name, id)`, what you ask for is as easy as:

```
insert into mytable (name, id)
values ('Meete', 3), ('Meete', 4), ('Reza', 3), ('Reza', 4), ('dexer', 3), ('dexer', 4)
on duplicate key update name = values(name);
```

And you can always generate the CVS list as needed:

```
select name, group_concat(id order by id) as all_ids
from mytable
group by name
```

Recommended reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716)

Comment: can't we use update and set in it as schema would remain the same